# Oracle SQL Developer - Database Diff - How to choose a different schema

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have Oracle SQL Developer 3.2 installed.

I want to a a Tools -> Database Diff.  How do I choose a schema other the user's own schema?  I looked through the settings and am not able to find it.  Does anyone know?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found it.  I had to click the "More" button on the screen where you choose the Source & Destination.